# Sharepoint 2013 Online Workflow Check all list items for dates close to expiration

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint 2013 online list that has the following parameters:

- Name
- Medical Card Expiration Date
- Company

I am trying to create a sharepoint work flow that will check the list daily for any DL expiration that are 30days or less from the current date and then email a specific person based on the branch for any record that has that expiration. I'm stuck on the theory of even how to approach this problem, either through the text editor or visio.

Here's my first attempt:

[image]

This would run when a new list item is created and is set to pause for one day and run again. However, this doesn't seem to be the right approach as it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Loop n Times. Use Loop w/ Condition since presumably you want this to run forever.

The loop while condition should be if exitLoop == Yes
Create two variables (todaysDate as date, exitLoop as bool)
before the loop set exitLoop to No
Inside the loop, set the variable to current date.
If Current Item:Medical Expiration Date > current date variable then email, set exitLoop to Yes (which will cause the loop to end)
else
Pause for x amount of time